# Can Botframework add a reaction to a user message?

Tags: botframework

Can bot add a reaction to a user message?
I tried to send an activity like this:

`{
   "type": "messageReaction",
   "reactionsAdded": [{ "type": "like" }],
   "replyToId": 1579278444192
}`

on this URL - `/v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId}`

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the channel you are wanting to implement this on. If *channel x* (Facebook, Slack, etc.) sends "reactions" as part of the activity and the service allows you to scope to it, then it is possible to return bot responses based on those.

The Botbuilder-Samples GitHub [25.message-reaction](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/25.message-reaction) Javascript sample demonstrates how this is achieved for Teams. The C# version can be referenced [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/25.message-reaction). You would need to adjust the code to look for the appropriate context/activity data points and filter on those to send a response back.

Hope of help!